# Background inside background - css

Tags: html, css

I have two images:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/xpwpwl.jpg
http://i59.tinypic.com/b7hocy.jpg

I need to use the image1 as background and over it i want to place image2 wich will be the background of my newsletter input form.

The way i found to do it until now is to place the first image as background and the secound as another background and it works well but in some resolutions the image2(inputbackground) moves into diferent places, and i want that to keep in the same position for almost all resolution.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="bgall">
    <div class="inputcontainer">
        <label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type your email" />
        </label>            
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bgall {
    background-image: url('../img/image1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: contain;
    height:564px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.inputcontainer {
    background-image: url('../img/image2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-right: 19.5%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 93px;
    float: right;
}

label {
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to change the relative values of margin inside the `.inputcontainer` to absolute ones.

```
margin-top: 25%;
margin-right: 19.5%;
```

to something like

```
margin-top: 250px;
margin-right: 195px;
```

Or values appropriate for your images.

Comment: and change the background-size from contain to an absolute value